# Accessing ActiveRecord models from MongoDB application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rails-activerecord

I have an old app built in Rails 3 using MongoDB for the database (Mongoid as the adapter).

I am moving it to Rails 4 and using MySQL. My plan is to map the collections into their own tables through a script and copy the data. I'm comfortable doing that part. What I cannot for the life of me figure out is how to connect to the MySQL DB.

I have created the new app in Rails 4 and the new DB and, as an example, a table for `Contacts` which maps to the collection in the MongoDB.  What I want to do is find all contacts in Mongo, then connect to the MySQL DB and insert the records into the table.

How do I do that last part?

Thanks

Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this as follows.

1) Created the db schema in the new application. At this stage I didn't worry about associations as I would be setting association ids manually.

2) In a file I called `transition.rb` in the old app, I defined migration classes for each of the classes I wanted to transfer e.g. for the class `Product`, I defined a transition class called `NewProduct` using the following pattern:

```
class NewProduct < ActiveRecord::Base

  file = File.open("#{Rails.root}" + "/config/database.yml")
  dbconfig = YAML::load(file)
  establish_connection(dbconfig["development"])
  self.table_name = "products"

end
```

By adding the `mysql2` gem to the old MongoDB application, I was able to use this pattern to connect to the relevant tables in the new application.

3) For each of the classes, I then iterated over the existing records, mapping them to the new tables through the migration classes. There are some challenges where MySQL doesn't have the columns available to map directly e.g. no `Array` column type in MySQL. For these situations, I created a separate class and manually created associations.

There were certainly some parts of trial and error but on the whole it has worked quite well. The only part I couldn't complete programatically was associating uploaded images and documents back to the relevant products however due to the file naming structure for those uploads, it won't be a huge amount of manual effort to create the associations.

For those who are interested [this is the gist of the file I used](https://gist.github.com/robinjfisher/a6a2541cca07020e5e98).